# How to detect first authentication with google and firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I want to know how I can detect the first time a user enters google with my app (since I need to ask some extra information).
My code:

```dart
void _submitGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = await GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    );

    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(user.isAnonymous != null);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  }
```

Comment: I use a collection in cloud firestore to achieve that. If there is no user there, its first time that user logged in my app.

Comment: great, I'll do that